# Javascript Coin Flip Beginner

Tags: javascript, random

```
<script>

function myfunction () {
    var x = Math.random();

    if (x > 0.5) {
        document.write("Heads!");
    } else {
        document.write("Tails!");
    }
}

</script>
```

The following code is supposed to print either **Heads!** or **Tails!** as if a coin was being flipped. However, it does not seem to work.

Comment: Do you actually call the function?

Comment: where are you calling the function  ? call the function by `myfunction ()` under the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the function:

```js
function myfunction () {
     var x = (Math.random());
     if (x > 0.5) {
          document.write("Heads!");
     }else {
          document.write("Tails!");
     } 
}
myfunction(); //add this
```